# how to get effect of IP rules script in RHEL 6?

Tags: rhel, iptables, ip, iptables-persistent

I have written one `ip.sh` file in that I have written one rule and then saved the iprules with the corresponding commands. Now when I opened `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` nothing is reflecting. I need the steps for this to get effect of new iprules and I want to restore the old file.

Comment: @Rabin Thanks for the answer. i have written a rule like  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT. after that when i run nmap -v -p 443 127.0.0.1, it's showing the status was closed. how to change the status from closed to open.

Answer (score 0):

1. run you `ip.sh` script and setup your iptables
2. make sure you rules are applied `iptables -nvL | less`
3. save you rules with `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i have written a rule like iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT. after that when i run nmap -v -p 443 127.0.0.1, it's showing the status was closed. how to change the status from closed to open.

Comment: lo interface a usually not blocked, please post your full iptables with the command `iptables -nvL`